# Is there a built-in function "none"?

Tags: r, function

I hope the question is not too foolish.

Is there a built-in R function that returns `TRUE` when all the cases are `FALSE`?

Similar to `any()` or `all()` but when, in the case of a logical vector of 2, `TRUE` `TRUE` returns `FALSE`, `TRUE` `FALSE` returns `FALSE` and `FALSE` `FALSE` returns `TRUE`.

I would call it `none()`.

Comment: How about negating the `any` i.e. `!any(c(FALSE, FALSE))`

Comment: Yes, it works. Good enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `!` with `any`

```
!any(c(FALSE, FALSE))
```

Answer (score 3):

`Negate(any)` ?

```
> none <- Negate(any)
> none(c(TRUE,TRUE))
[1] FALSE
> none(c(TRUE,FALSE))
[1] FALSE
> none(c(FALSE,FALSE))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You could have called the function `none`, like the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Or `all`:

```
all(!vec)
```

Or using `sum`:

```
sum(vec)==0
```

where `vec` is your vector.